# Consequences following a failure of the golden throne/death of the emperor?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Following the Warhammer 40k lore, it seems as if the golden throne is coming closer to a critical failure or at least the actual existence of the emperor is being hinted as endangered more often in the latest books.

I am now wondering what the consequence for the empire would be if the golden throne/the emperor are no more.

Would the warp travel fail to work since the Astronomican would not exist anymore?

Would the chaos gods overrun the empire?

Comment: This feels very speculative. I don't know enough about the lore to know if the consequences have been speculated upon in-universe though

Comment: The Emperor will never die and to even THINK it is the most vile heresy!

Comment: There is various speculation in universe, but with the amount of lore that there has been there are lots of different opinions. These have also changed with the release of the Horus Heresy novels as this has freshed out the real reason why the golden throne exists. Before these novels the reason for the throne was not really known

Comment: @Valorum There are a lot of in-universe prophecies, the most founded is probably the one by the cabal predicting that everything will go south.

Answer (score 3):

One book this was addressed was [Legion by Dan Abnett](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Legion_(Novel)). The cabal, a group of xenos psychers (among them [Eldrad Ulthran](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Eldrad_Ulthran)), foresaw what would happen:

> The foreseen outcome of the Heresy, the Cabal saw the Emperor giving his life to kill Horus, becoming a howling rictus trapped inside the Golden Throne. They believed that this path would lead to stagnation, and stagnation to decay. This decay would accelerate, continually allowing the Chaos powers to grow and spread their influence, until after ten or twenty thousand years of misery, the entire galaxy would be consumed by Chaos.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on the Cabal](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Cabal)

There are also some inquisitors believing that if the Emperor dies, he will be reborn as a chaos god, which is the Star Child theory.

> Over the millennia since the Emperor's internment upon the Golden Throne, the link between his body and soul has become increasingly tenuous. As the Emperor's spirit drifts through the warp, much of its energies have been dissolved, except for a tiny core that remained whole. So long as this portion of the Emperor's soul survived, there remained hope for humanity, for just as the New Man was born of the collective souls of the Shamans, so too may the Emperor's soul be reborn one day. This potential was merely a child awaiting birth, the Star Child. The Star Child also represents the human portion of the warp.

The Star Child is also suggested (by a fragment of the Emperor's mind) as being the compassion which the Emperor cast from himself in order to destroy his most beloved Primarch-son, Horus. Inquisitor Jaq Draco believed that Shining Path upon which the Numen may be born originates within a special node of the Webway, known as Uigebealach, where time flows backwards. He believed that by visiting this special crossroads, and achieving a triumph by resurrecting a lost soul, he may accelerate the birth of the Numen. However, upon his death, he had instead achieved Apotheosis, becoming a tiny part of the Numen as a diffuse hydrogen atom in the void will one day condense into a star.

> From the Lexicanum [article on the Star Child](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Star_Child)

So, there are a lot of different in-universe prophecies (I've only listed to the most extreme, one being that the whole galaxy will become an Eye of Terror, the other that the God Emperor will be a Chaos God and protect mankind) but no way to know until GW lets the God Emperor really die.

Comment: Isn't the first prophecy what actually happened? The Emperor was trapped on the Golden Throne, the Imperium became stagnant and decaying, and 10,000 years later (viz, now) Chaos seems poised to finally break the Imperium apart.

Comment: @Cadence So far, yes. But we don't know if e.g. the prayers of the believers have an effect. 10k years of trillions of humans believing the emperor is a god may have elevated him to a god. That's the thing with predictions, a lot can change. Otherwise, eldar would win every battle with the help of the farseers.